# как создать html шаблон в angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Есть код

```
    <div class="info-block__title">
                  <img src="../../../assets/image/svg/warning — red.svg" alt="" style="margin-right: 5px;" class="info-block__center-img">Возникла непредвиденная ошибка
                  <p class="error_text" >тут текст
<a class="error_a" href="mailto:info@a-3.ru?subject=Ошибка работы портала">напишите нам</a>.</p>
                  <!--{{state.current_state.error_supplier_text}}  Эта штука почему-то не выводится и не определена-->
                  <button  type="button" class="button-standard amount" [ngClass]="'green'" style="margin-top:20px;" routerLink="/categories">
                    <span class="button-standard__text">
                      ВЕРНУТЬСЯ К ВЫБОРУ УСЛУГ
                    </span>
                  </button>
                </div>
```

Хочу заменить в html файле этот блок на  и применять этот блок ошибки в нескольких файлах, но не знаю, где точно нужно объявлять все эти файлы.
Знаю, что нужно в .ts файле объявить

```
@Component({
  selector: 'error',
  templateUrl: './error.html',
```

и ещё где-то

```
import { error } from '@app/error';
```

подскажите точные инструкции по созданию таких шаблонов
слышал про ng-include, но не могу найти, как точно её применять

Comment: вы как-то странно смешиваете angularjs и angular, директива ng-include доступна в angularjs

Comment: @overthesanity получается нужно делать с помощью компонента? как тогда реализовывать логику, кроме component и import?